# what is this ? Mootools class or object?

Tags: javascript

I view a file and see that

```
var Modal = {
  presets: {....},
  initialize: function(){...},
  addClick: function(){...},
  extend: $extend
}
Modal.extend(Events.prototype);
Modal.extend(Options.prototype);
Modal.extend(Chain.prototype);
```

i think Modal is a object.

addClick key with value is a function

i call it like addClick function.

in this function have a line

this.setOptions();

and i catch a error : this.setOptions is not a function

Answer (score 1):

You apparently don't have an idea what you are asking for. You should provide good details, so we can know what you really want.

1. Modal is an object (since it's declared with { and })
2. The object can contain any other kind of objects (it can be a string, a function or another object)
3. **this** refers to the function "addclick". There is probably a missing function or a missing prototype.

Comment: thank 
you can show me where to download plugin Tips.js of mootools1.1